# Representing number and their frequencies by a single number

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

At each step of a problem i am either given a number (0<=number<=9) or i am asked about the frequencies of each number from 0 to 9.

I know there are many other ways to do it but i am specifically interested in using just a single number(FINAL) and finding out the frequencies of 0 to 9.

So i thought of representing numbers (0 to 9) to prime numbers.

Numbers -> Prime Numbers

0 ->2

1->3

2->5

3->7

4->11

5->13

6->17

7->19

8->23

9->29

So, whenever i will get a number,i will multiply the corresponding prime numbers to the Final number.And when i will be asked about the frequencies of the numbers i will divide the FINAL number by the prime numbers to get the frequency.

for eg:

Input: 1,3,2,3 
FINAL:3*7*5*7

I can get frequency of 3 by dividing FINAL by 7 which will give me 2.

I am getting my answer through this but the FINAL number becomes very large which i don't want.Is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: I think it is more algorithm problem, I would just make an array of 10 integers to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

But dividing $3\times7\times5\times7$ by $7$ yields $105$, not $2$!

You need prime factorization here which gives you $735=3^{1}\times5^{1}\times7^{2}$, and the exponents are the frequencies. If you just want to make the sum a smaller number, one approach is to use the $\log$ of the primes which converts multiplication into addition. That is, $0\to\log(2),1\to\log(3),\cdots 
$

So you will save $S=\log(3)+\log(7)+\log(5)+\log(7)$.
Note, however that this is almost as cumbersome as storing a large number since you need to store the result with high decimal accuracy. Since you cannot define the $\log()$ values with infinite precision and need to truncate somewhere, there would be a cumulative error as you add more numbers which eventually can lead to a wrong result when you want to factorize the final number. You may consider it if the number of occurrence of the items is not so large.

Comment: You misunderstood my statement, i wanted to keep dividing by 7 until the number is not divisible.Which will give me 2 as the number of occurences

Comment: I understood your approach. The note was for the sake of clarity (you can add the explanation in the question as well). What you do is prime factorization.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the standard way of doing this is making 10 variables for each of the numbers. But if you really want to do it in 1 variable, here's a better way to do it.

1. Find how many bits your variable and programming language support. Let's say it's $64$ bytes.
2. Compute $(2^{64})^{1/10}$. It's approximately $84.45$. Let $C=84$.
3. Now each time you get input $k$, add $C^k$ to your variable.
4. After you get every input, find base $C$ representation of the variable to get the answer.

This is better than the method suggested in OP, since it can store up to $C-1$ occurrences of each number, and OP's method can only support less than $64$ occurrences of number.